# MySQL join same table twice to fetch value based on different IDs

Tags: mysql

I have three tables with the following structures:

**`users` Table**

| id | first_name | last_name | company | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | John | Doe | Company Name | ... |
| 6 | Joe | Bloggs | Bloggs Inc. | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**`vehicles` Table**

| id | name | user_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 VW Tiguan | 5 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**`bids` Table**

| id | bidder_user_id | vehicle_id | amount | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 4000 | .... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I am trying to get all bids along with the ID of the vehicle being bid on, the name of the `user_id` who owns the vehicle, the name of the `bidder_user_id` who bid on the vehicle, and the bid `amount`.

My problem is that it seems I need to conduct two `JOIN` statements on the `users` table in order to match the `bidder_user_id` from `bids`, and `vehicle.user_id` from `vehicles` however that doesn't seem to be possible.

Here is my query so far:

```sql
SELECT
    vehicle_id AS vehicleID,
    vehicles.user_id AS sellerID,
    bids.bidder_user_id AS bidderID,
    CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS bidderName,
    users.company AS bidderCompanyName,
    bids.amount AS bid_amount,
FROM `bids`
    JOIN `users` ON bids.bidder_user_id = users.id
    JOIN `vehicles` ON bids.vehicle_id = vehicle.id
ORDER BY vehicle_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the `users` table twice:

```
SELECT bids.id, 
  bids.amount, 
  CONCAT(owners.first_name, ' ', owners.last_name) as owner, 
  CONCAT(bidders.first_name, ' ', bidders.last_name) as bidder
FROM bids
JOIN users as bidders
  ON bids.bidder_user_id = bidders.id
JOIN vehicles 
  ON bids.vehicle_id = vehicles.id
JOIN users as owners
  ON vehicles.user_id = owners.id
```